# Wildcards vs SuperType in method declaration

Tags: java, wildcard

Can someone please explain why we would ever use `? extends ...`. To me, it seems that I can always use the super type whenever I want to specify such a condition in my code. For example, `? extends Number` can always be replaced with `Number` right?

Consider the following

```
public static double numberAdd(List<Number> list) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Number x : list) {
        sum += x.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

vs.

```
public static double genericAdd(List<? extends Number> list) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Number x : list) {
        sum += x.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Both do the same thing^. Any reason why you would use the `List<? extends Number>` version?

Comment: What if you want to generically add a `List<Integer>`? Try that with both, see what happens.

Comment: The first method will only accept an argument of type `List<Number>`, the second one will accept any list whose type extends `Number` (`List<Integer>`, `List<Double>` etc).

Comment: See [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) - mine of information on this topic

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks a lot. This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po describes exactly what was the source of my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberAdd(List<Number> list)` will only accept a `List<Number>`.

`genericAdd(List<? extends Number> list)` will accept a `List<Number>` or a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Double>`, etc...

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you suggested and there's clearly a difference. the reason for this behavior is explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po
I'll mark your answer as accepted soon as it lets me